# Is this SQL/NoSQL/DSL injection in Opensearch python client?

Tags: python, sql-injection, opensearch, nosql-injection

The Opensearch documentation around using the low-level python client is [here](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/python-low-level/).

When executing search queries it shows the following example:

```
# Search for the document.
q = 'miller'
query = {
  'size': 5,
  'query': {
    'multi_match': {
      'query': q,
      'fields': ['title^2', 'director']
    }
  }
}

response = client.search(
    body = query,
    index = index_name
)
print('\nSearch results:')
print(response)
```

Is this vulnerable to **SQL** / **DSL** injection?

I'm surprised there isn't an example with a parameterised query. If this is vulnerable to an injection attack then I guess one would have to come up with their own validations to sanitise the input parameters...

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not SQL injection, because OpenSearch is not an SQL implementation.

The worst you could do is inject an [OpenSearch DSL query string](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/query-dsl/full-text/query-string/), if your `q` variable is based on untrusted input. That could result in a DSL syntax error, or a search you didn't intend.

This could be considered code injection, but it's not likely to cause much harm.